# reverse a RF rolling code

Tags: crc, remote, unknown-data

I have the following codes from a rolling code RF garage fob I want to duplicate.
There is a duplicator remote that able to get one code and learn the sequrence from it:
https://www.ebay.com/itm/V2-Remote-Control-V2-Phox-2-or-4-TRC-4-TXC-2-TXC-4-Handy-2-Handy-4/174325345483?hash=item289699accb:g:vSMAAOSw--Ne8IHi
But I need to understand how to produce the sequence myself to operate it from my smart-house hub
I can produce more if necessary but this is a sample from the series:
Bytes 0-8 are constants
Byte 10 changes every 4th click

```
_____________
ff641a07f72f9
ff641a07fd2c7
ff641a07f3266
ff641a07f9258
ff641a07f4de9
ff641a07fedd7
ff641a07f0d76
ff641a07fad48
ff641a07ff0f5
ff641a07f50cb
ff641a07fb06a
ff641a07f1054
ff641a07fcfe5
ff641a07f6fdb
ff641a07f8f7a
ff641a07f2f44
ff641a07f8efd
ff641a07f2ec3
ff641a07fce62
ff641a07f6e5c
ff641a07fb1ed
ff641a07f11d3
ff641a07ff172
ff641a07f514c
```

**Edit:**
Some more samples:
https://pastebin.com/qXgFqKZa (note that it was a long capture and some codes may have been missed)

and one sample captured with inspectrum
[image: Inspectrum sample]

Comment: Each message has 13 characters...  are these meant to be 13 "bytes" ? or ~7 hex bytes missing something at the start or finish?

Comment: What's the model of the garage door device? Can you produce a couple hundred or more messages? Pastebin the hex.

Comment: yes, i can produce many more. there are only 13 bytes + preamble I'll upload an image of one sample with inspecturm

Answer (score 2):

Partial Answer:

Looking only at the last 2bytes in binary shows some patterns where groups of bits are being flipped between groups of 4 messages ( Not2, Not3), or between groups of 8 (Not4). The unboxed bits influence the value of Not2 in some way.

[image]

Comment: found some more info on FCC site. just approving the 52 bits with 16 bits rolling code at the end(page 28): [fccLink](https://fccid.io/RSK-V2-TSC-4/Test-Report/Test-Report-396476.pdf)

Comment: Looking again in your analysis, instead of block of constant, not4 not8. It is simply bit reordering. But after some occasion there is a “not” operation